# Solve a complex number equation

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, proof-writing, terminology

I am start learning complex number in my university. I don't know a lot about complex number but I know most of the facts and rules about them.
I have the equation:
$$z^{10} + (z - 1)^{10} = 0$$
It has $10$ roots and they are $z_1$, $\overline{z_1}$, $z_2$, $\overline{z_2}$,..., $z_5$, $\overline{z_5}$. We want to find value of:
$$\sum_{i=1}^5 {\frac{1}{z_i \overline{z_i}}}$$

another method for simplification:

$\frac{1}{z_k} = 1 - e^{i\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{10}}$

we get modulus from both side:
$\frac{1}{|z_k|}=|1-\cos(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{10}) - i\sin(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{10}) =$

$1 - (1 - 2\sin(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{20})^{2}-2i\sin(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{20})\cos(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{20})|=$

$2|\sin(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{20})||\sin(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{20})-i\cos(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{20})| =$

for $1 \le k \le 5$:

$\frac{1}{|z_k|} = 2\sin(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{20})$

Is it possible to help me solve this?  Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is it you want to prove?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: @Amin Borjian Please check if I  re-edited your question correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry. I left and I come back now. I edited it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We will show
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^5 {\frac{1}{z_k \overline{z_k}}}=10.$$

Note that $z^{10} + (z - 1)^{10} = 0$ is equivalent to
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{10}=-1=e^{-i\pi}.$$
Hence for $k=1,2,3,4,5$, 
$$1-\frac{1}{z_k}=e^{i\pi(2k-1)/10}$$
which implies 
$$\frac{1}{z_k \overline{z_k}}=(1-e^{i\pi(2k-1)/10})(1-e^{-i\pi(2k-1)/10})=2-2\cos\left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{10}\right).$$
Therefore 
$$\sum_{k=1}^5 {\frac{1}{z_k \overline{z_k}}}=\sum_{k=1}^5\left(2-2\cos\left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{10}\right)\right)=10-2\sum_{k=1}^5\cos\left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{10}\right).$$
So it remains to show that the following sum is zero
$$\sum_{k=1}^5\cos\left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{10}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{10}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{10}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{10}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{9\pi}{10}\right)$$
which holds by the symmetry $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I checking it now. I have a question. is this true? $|\frac{w}{z}| = \frac{|w|}{|z|}$

Comment: Yes, It's true.

Comment: I use another way to get the simple form of $\frac{1}{z_k \overline{z_k}}$. I added it to my question.

Comment: why my answer is different from yours?

Comment: Oh. I forgot. It must be powered by two.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=\frac{w+1}2$ and $v=w+\frac1w$.

Solving $v=w+\frac1w$ for $w$ is just solving $w^2-vw+1=0$ using the quadratic formula:
$$
w=\frac{v\pm\sqrt{v^2-4}}2\tag1
$$
Applying the binomial theorem to $v^k=\left(w+\frac1w\right)^k$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
v^5&=w^5+5w^3+10w+10w^{-1}+5w^{-3}+w^{-5}\\
v^3&=w^3+3w+3w^{-1}+w^{-3}\\
v&=w+w^{-1}
\end{align}\tag2
$$
We can take linear combinations of the equations in $(2)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
w+w^{-1}&=v\\
w^3+w^{-3}&=v^3-3v\\
w^5+w^{-5}&=v^5-5v^3+5v
\end{align}\tag3
$$
Therefore, applying $(3)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=z^{10}+(z-1)^{10}\\
&=2^{-10}\left((w+1)^{10}+(w-1)^{10}\right)\\
&=2^{-9}\left(w^{10}+45w^8+210w^6+210w^4+45w^2+1\right)\\
&=2^{-9}w^5\left(\color{#C00}{w^5}\color{#090}{+45w^3}\color{#00F}{+210w+210w^{-1}}\color{#090}{+45w^{-3}}\color{#C00}{+w^{-5}}\right)\\
&=2^{-9}w^5\left(\color{#C00}{v^5-5v^3+5v}\color{#090}{+45v^3-135v}\color{#00F}{+210v}\right)\\
&=2^{-9}w^5v\left(v^4+40v^2+80\right)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
$w=0$ does not satisfy $(w+1)^{10}+(w-1)^{10}=0$. However, $(1)$ says that if $v=0$, then $w=\pm i$, which does satisfy $(w+1)^{10}+(w-1)^{10}=0$. Applying $z=\frac{w+1}2$ to $w=\pm i$ yields the roots
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{z=\frac{1\pm i}2}\tag5
$$
Furthermore, if $v\ne0$, equation $(4)$ says we need
$$
\begin{align}
v^4+40v^2+80=0
&\implies v=\pm2i\sqrt{5\pm2\sqrt5}\tag6\\
&\implies w=\pm i\sqrt{5\color{#C00}{\pm}2\sqrt5}\pm i\sqrt{6\color{#C00}{\pm}2\sqrt5}\tag7\\
&\implies\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{z=\frac{1\pm i\sqrt{5\color{#C00}{\pm}2\sqrt5}\pm i\sqrt{6\color{#C00}{\pm}2\sqrt5}}2}\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(6)$: quadratic formula
$(7)$: apply $(1)$
$(8)$: apply $z=\frac{w+1}2$

Note that the red $\pm$'s must be the same.

$(5)$ and $(8)$ give all $10$ roots.

Comment: It's so complex for me! However thanks for that.

Comment: @AminBorjian: It involves a couple of substitutions that allow the equation to be solved using only the quadratic formula. I will add some comments that might make it easier to understand.